# Is $\sum_{a=0}^m\sum_{b=0}^n\cos(abx)$ always positive?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, trigonometric-series

Fix integers $m,n\geq0$.

> Do we have the inequality $\displaystyle\sum_{a=0}^m\sum_{b=0}^n\cos(abx)>0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$?

We can also write this function as
\begin{align*}
\sum_{a=0}^m\sum_{b=0}^n\cos(abx)&=m+n+1+\sum_{a=1}^m\sum_{b=1}^n\cos(abx)\\
&=m+n+1+\sum_{a=1}^m\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\sin((n+1/2)ax)}{\sin(ax/2)}-1\right)\\
&=\frac{m}{2}+n+1+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{a=1}^mD_n(ax),
\end{align*}
where
$$D_n(x)=\frac{\sin((n+1/2)x)}{\sin(x/2)}$$
is the Dirichlet kernel (up to a factor of $2\pi$, depending on your convention).

Using this formula, it is easy to check the conjecture for small values of $m$ and $n$ ([desmos link](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/g7jb6fx98y)).

Comment: Did you try to obtain a formula for the sum of Dirichlet kernels using $\sin t = \Re e^{it}$ and the formula for geometric sums?

Comment: I don't think that there is a closed form formula for the sum of Dirichlet kernels. The denominators make things tricky. You could phrase this whole question in terms of the real part of $\sum\sum e^{abx}$, which makes it easier to see why the denominators prevent you from applying the geometric series formula twice.

Comment: Yes, sorry I missed the denominator.

Comment: Any information about this question (e.g., source)?

Comment: each cosine is bounded by $1$ and $-1$. So perhaps we could use this to find lower and upper bounds

Comment: @ThomasBrowning can u do $m=n, x=1$?

Comment: @RiverLi It arose in the context of this mathoverflow question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/405593

Comment: @mathworker21 I do not know how to solve that case

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No! Consider the case $m = n$ and $x = \frac{8π}{4n + 3}$. We have

\begin{split}
\sum_{a=0}^n \sum_{b=0}^n \cos(abx)
&= \frac{3n}{2} + 1 + \frac12 \sum_{a=1}^n \frac{\sin\left(\left(n + \frac12\right)ax\right)}{\sin\left(\frac12ax\right)} \\
&= \frac{3n}{2} + 1 + \frac12 \sum_{a=1}^n \frac{\sin\left(2πa - \frac{2πa}{4n + 3}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{4πa}{4n + 3}\right)} \\
&= \frac{3n}{2} + 1 + \frac12 \sum_{a=1}^n \frac{\sin\left(-\frac{2πa}{4n + 3}\right)}{\sin\left(\frac{4πa}{4n + 3}\right)} \\
&= \frac{3n}{2} + 1 - \frac14 \sum_{a=1}^n \sec\left(\frac{2πa}{4n + 3}\right) \\
&< \frac{3n}{2} + 1 - \frac14 \int_0^n \sec\left(\frac{2πa}{4n + 3}\right)\,da \\
&= \frac{3n}{2} + 1 + \frac{4n + 3}{8π} \ln \tan \frac{3π}{4(4n + 3)} \\
&\sim \frac{3n}{2} + 1 + \frac{4n + 3}{8π} \ln \frac{3π}{4(4n + 3)} \\
&→ -∞ \quad \text{as $n → ∞$}.
\end{split}

We can confirm this by plotting the exact sum at $m = n$ and $x = \frac{8π}{4n + 3}$ (blue); it first becomes negative at $n = 3286$. By optimizing $x$ near $\frac{8π}{4n + 3}$ to minimize the sum (orange), we find a slightly earlier negative value at $m = n = 3161$ and $x = 0.001987239$.

[image: plot]

Comment: excellent counterexample!

Comment: Incredible! I had no idea!

Comment: From this approach, we can derive an infinite family of counterexamples when $m=n$. In particular, any function $f(n)$ such that $1/f(n)\in(n+1/2,n+1)$ for all positive $n$ yields a counterexample when $x=2\pi f(n)$.

Comment: Wow. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Not quite. $x = \frac{4π}{2n + 1}$ and $x = \frac{2π}{n + 1}$ do not lead to counterexamples, so neither does any function sufficiently close to them. You need a stronger condition like $\frac{2π}{x} ∈ (n + \frac12 + ε, n + 1 - ε)$ for some *constant* $ε > 0$. (But the math is uniquely simple for $x = \frac{8π}{4n + 3}$, which allows the double-angle cancellation on line 4.)